# app crashes while pushing view controller again

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to one push view controller from button action. I am able to push my view controller and see the second view controller page. Now am clicking back button and coming again to my first view controller. Now when again I press the button my app crashes without any log messages at      `[self.navigationController pushViewController:about animated:NO];`

Here is my code,

FirstVC.m

```
- (IBAction) proceedButton:(id)sender {
    if(news == nil) {
        news = [NewsViewController instantiate];
    }
    [UIView  beginAnimations:@"ShowNews" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
     self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
     UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle : @"Back"
                                                         style : UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                        target : nil
                                                        action : nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:news animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

SecondVC.m

```
+ (instancetype)instantiate {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NewsScreen" bundle: nil];
return (NewsViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"About"];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    .....
    .....
}
```

Checked values for navigation controller, tried changing my animation to YES. But it doesn't work. Kindly help. TIA.

Comment: What is your storyboard name?

Comment: Show your crash log?

Comment: no crash logs showing up.

Comment: What does it do? Just close? Or breakpoint error?

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad its NewsScreen

Comment: @Ivan simply crashes

Comment: Check if your instantiate returns what you are expecting. Does it return nil?

Comment: @Ivan Am able to see my insatiate variable news value.

Comment: If there is no log how do you know the error is at pushViewController?

Comment: it crashes in that line of code with a red line. Tried adding exception breakpoint and tried catching exception in main.m file. Nothing works.

Comment: So it stops there in red (Like a kind of exception). You would be able to click  'Continue debugging' like if you stopped there with a custom breakpoint, if you try to continue the log will show the error after some continues.

Comment: @Ivan No. Even I continued. It's not showing any crash logs.